# Apply email rules to existing emails

Tags: icloud, email, mail-rules

I've added a email rule in iCloud to copy emails with a specific from address to a folder.  This is working fine, all new mails are moved to that folder. Is there a way to apply the rule also to mails that I've received before I crated the rule?

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all your mails, then right click on it => `Apply rules`

Or as [Matteo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/10888/matteo) point out : <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: or cmd+shift+L instead of Apply Rules

Comment: I think this is only related to local rules in apple mail and not for rules added to icloud in using a browser.